# homebrew boost: where are the python bindings?

Tags: python, macos, boost, homebrew, boost-python

I installed boost and boost-python using homebrew, and can access these packages when I supply the direct path the a C++ compiler. However, Python can't "see" boost. Why could this be happening? How can I troubleshoot this problem?

```
>>> import boost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named boost
```

I tried finding the so file for importing, but I cannot find it on my system

`$ mdfind boost | grep boost | grep .so`

To give some context, I am trying to pass a communicator to a C function. I need to pass a boost communicator. When I pass mpi4py I get the error

```
mymod.run_mymod_mpi(str, mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm, str, str, _ExcInfo)
did not match C++ signature:
    run_mymod_mpi(char*, boost::mpi::communicator {lvalue}, char*, char*, boost::python::api::object)
```

Does homebrew `boost-python` come with the boost pytjon bindings? If not, how can I install them?

EDIT
I opened [an issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/49382) on github, now tagged with `help-wanted`. This feature is not currently supported by homebrew.

Comment: What do you mean by `import boost`? What are you trying to do? Boost.Python is a library for creating Python bindings for your C++ code. You create a shared object (I think dylib on mac) that exposes your C++ code using Boost.Python and then import that shared object in your Python code. You should read some tutorials.

Comment: In the past I have been able to `import boost` using python

Comment: Ah ok, that's the Python bindings for MPI created using Boost.Python, similar to what I described in the last comment. Make sure the path to the mpi bindings you just installed is on your `sys.path`.

Comment: @Praetorian What might the path to mpi bindings look like? I've tried various permutations of `boost/1.60.0_1/include/boost/python`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I imagine that's very specific to the package you downloaded.